# Does HTTP `TRACE` method do the same thing as `curl --trace`?

Tags: curl, http

Does HTTP `TRACE` method do the same thing as `curl --trace`?

Stephen said at [Does `curl -v` show the complete HTTP request including the body?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/497706/does-curl-v-show-the-complete-http-request-including-the-body#comment915918_497707):

> the TRACE HTTP method affects the server’s behaviour, not the client’s (curl’s)

As far as what curl receives is concerned,  HTTP `TRACE` method and `curl --trace` seem to provide the same information to `curl`. Correct? If not, what differences are between the information provided by HTTP `TRACE` method and information provided by `curl --trace`?

If considering how the information is collected, do the two ways do the same thing to collect the information?

Thanks.

Comment: [HTTP Guide from Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HTTP `TRACE` method provides a "message test" mechanism.  It basically returns back what the client sent.

So, for example if a client sent

```
TRACE / HTTP/1.1
Host: foo
Bar: baz
```

then it might expect back something like

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: myserver
Date: Wed, 31 Jan 2019 01:37:48 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: message/http
Content-Length: 39

TRACE / HTTP/1.1
Host: foo
Bar: baz
```

This is totally unrelated to the curl `--trace` option, which provides detailed information around the normal request (eg GET) made by the client.

Comment: FWIW, the only purpose of the `TRACE` method is to generate a `400`  or `405` error from the server. With many sites (eg. google or facebook), the `EXTERMINATE` method will do that, too.

Comment: @mosvy Yes, well, my own sites respond "400 Bad request", but that's not what the TRACE method is for :-)